# MYSQL won't run

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I get this when I start MYSQL?

```
20:43:41  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:43:41  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:43:41  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:43:41  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:43:41  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:43:41  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
20:43:41  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Can someone please help me? MYSQL starts for about 5 seconds and then closes... I can't find a fix any where so I decided to post it here, if you can fix, don't hesitate to comment.

Error log:

```
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-10-11 20:43:36 8c8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-10-11 20:43:36 8c8  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Binlog end
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-10-11 20:43:36 2124 [Note] C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\cpps\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: first of all i would recommend using xampp

Comment: This is Xampp and Windows.

Comment: You have this: `InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2`. I'd guess you have an access permissions issue.

Comment: So do I CHMOD a file?

Comment: Run MySQL as admin or do not run it from `C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\cpps\mysql`. Put it in a separate folder in the root, for example, or move `data` folder there

Comment: Do you have skype?Close it it might block the port.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't offering much information about how you got to this point.  It's clear from the error message that the InnoDB storage engine code can't create a necessary temp file.

I had a similar problem when I reinstalled MySQL and tried to move over my `data` folder from a soon-to-be-retired hard drive.  It's a directory-protection problem.

Don't do what I first did: try mucking around with protections (chmod, etc). There lies madness -- seriously. If you have done this, uninstall and then reinstall MySQL.

Try running mysqld in console mode to figure out what is going on. That's documented here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-start-command-line.html

NOTICE that you probably should use a cmd prompt with administrative privilege to do this. It's possible your problem starting InnoDB is because you're trying to run mysqld without sufficient privileges. To start a command prompt with administrative privileges, make sure you're logged in with an administratory account, then follow these directions. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx

If mysqld starts up ok when you run it this way,  you can try `--install`ing it as a Windows Service. See this writeup:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-start-service.html

It might already be installed as a service, in which case your attempt to install it will fail. If that happens, use `--remove` first and then use `--install`.

Next, to make sure it's working as a service, try opening up the service (Start / Run services.msc). Find the MySQL service. Try stopping it and starting it with the service manager.  If it starts successfully, that's great.

Finally, make sure the service has a Startup Type of automatic (or Automatic Delayed...). Then, reboot your Windows box and make sure MySql started up.